# Restoring deleted product (0) to (1) in database

Tags: php, pdo

I have a code that should work, but it doesn't and I can't find the solution.
Inside my database I have column deleted 
If a product is deleted it is 1

[[image: Deleted]]

If the product is deleted it goes into Archives location from where it should be successfully restored when clicked on button to become 0 inside the database

[image]

This is what I tried with PHP :

```
   <?php
include_once "../konfiguracija.php";
include 'includes/head.php';
include 'includes/izbornik.php';
//Restore Product
if(isset($_GET['restore'])) {
 $id = sanitize($_GET['restore']);
 $restorirana=$veza->prepare("UPDATE products SET deleted = 0 WHERE id='$id';");
 $restorirana->execute();
 header('Location: Products.php');
}
?>
<?php
$format = new NumberFormatter("en_US",NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$p_result =$veza->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `deleted`=1;");
$p_result ->execute();
?>
<h2 class="text-center">Products</h2>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<hr>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed talbe-striped">
 <thead>
   <th>Restore</th>
   <th>Product</th>
   <th>Price</th>
   <th>Parent ~ Category</th>
   <th>Featured</th>
   <th>Sold</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <?php while ($product = $p_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
      $childId = $product['categories'];
       $catSql = $veza->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id='$childId';");
       $result= $catSql->execute();
       $child = $catSql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       $parentId = $child['parent'];
         $parentSql = $veza->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id='$parentId';");
        $parentSql->execute();
         $parent =$parentSql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $category = $parent['category'].'~'.$child['category'];
   ?>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <a href="products.php?restore=<?php echo $product['id']; ?>" class ="button"><i class="fas fa-undo"></i></a>
    </td>
    <td><?=$product['title'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $format->format ($product['price']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $category;?></td>
    <td><a href="products.php?featured=<?=(($product['featured']== 0)?'1':'0');?>&id=<?=$product['id'];?>"
      class ="button tiny"><i class="fas fa-<?=(($product['featured']==1)?'minus':'plus');?> fa-2x " ></i>
    </a>&nbsp <?=(($product['featured']==1)?'Featured Product': '');?></td>
    <td>0</td>
 </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
 </tbody>
</table>
<?php include 'includes/podnozje.php';
include_once 'includes/scripts.php';
 ?>*
```

When button "restore" is pressed no errors are outputted, the page redirects to products.php and the deleted stays the same inside the database.

Comment: Does `$id` have a value after `sanitize()`?

Comment: I tried to check it with print_r but I get no logs after redirect.Where should I check that?

Comment: Comment out the header redirect before doing var_dump()

Comment: Actually <a href="products.php?restore= redirected me , not the if set GET

Comment: still no outputs after doing this and using restore link

Comment: Nvm, just replace with - https://pastebin.com/8tUStESR - what's the out when you do a restore?

Comment: same as before, no outputs , only redirect

Comment: The code you posted is from file products.php right?

Comment: No, I think this might be the problem. It is archived.php

Comment: Can you pastebin products.php as well?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qdBs9BDw

Comment: Array ( [restore] => 20 ) !

Comment: Done. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restore link points to the wrong php file.

**Replace:**

```
products.php?restore=
```

**With:**

```
archived.php?restore=
```

Rename header `location`correctly to `products.php` and added `exit;` after redirection so no other codes will be executed after redirect call.

**From:**

```
 header('Location: Products.php');
```

**To:**

```
 header('Location: products.php');exit;
```